# Backup strategy for large FileStream database in Sql Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, backup, filestream

**Background:**

I've build a document management system for my company to manage company documents(~1TB, 1 million+ rows in File table).

The application were build using .net 4.8 with EF6. DB is SQL Server 2017. File are saved as FileStream BLOB in SQL Server. Files can be downloaded/uploaded via web frontend/API.

The DB size is roughly 1TB and 95% of those are filestream blob, with about 20% per year growth rate.

Our current backup strategy is:

- Full backup(weekly)
- Differential backup(daily)
- Translog backup (every 15 mins)

**Challenges** we are facing:

1. Full Backup will take 7-8 hours - normal operations may be affected due to the I/O capacity consumption of the backup operation.
2. DB Restore will take very long time if any disaster happened(this is our biggest concern).
3. Backup file size too big(full backup file is about 900GB)
4. All historical data need to be accessible so we cannot really archive the data.

**Question:**

1. Considering this scenario, what would be the best strategy for us regarding SQL Backup?
2. I've seen people using Filegroups to separate cold/hot data. As all files that already been uploaded will be read-only, is there a way we could utilize Filegroup in our system?

Answer (score 0):

> Considering this scenario, what would be the best strategy for us regarding SQL Backup?

I believe, current backup strategy (that you have mentioned) seems to be good in your case.

> Full Backup will take 7-8 hours - normal operations may be affected due to the I/O capacity consumption of the backup operation.

You would may want find correct time window to perform Full backup to reduce over-head on the server.

Identifying IO latency during backup (whether read/write) would help you to plan better i.e. does the delay (7-8 Hours) due to IO latency in reading backup or writing backups to shared location. Since you have full duration already, you can identify reading operation delay performing `BACKUP TO DISK = 'null'`. Probability (of the delay) more with write operation, in that case you may reduce the backup time by saving it locally/faster storage drive and move to regular shared location once backup done.

> DB Restore will take very long time if any disaster happened(this is our biggest concern).

Consider the FULL BACKUPS are slow during BACKUP and faster during RESTORE, which quite opposite in LO BACKUPS case. Thus, mentioned your backup strategy is good.

However, in your case for DR the best option is [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/log-shipping-and-replication-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) which periodically restores the LOG backups on secondary server, since the FULL backup restored only once there would not be much load either sides (Primary site and DR Site). Consider your regular LOG BACKUP (15 minutes) would be replaced with Log Shipping jobs.

With LS as DR Solution the recovery time is equal to the time that recent LOG Restoration can take.

> Backup file size too big(full backup file is about 900GB)

I believe, this is by standard compression level and maximum can be possible in SQL Engine, and there won't be much options to reduce the size of the backup.